# How to prove that a set with higher cardinality than the basis of a free module is linearly dependent

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a free $R$-module $M$ with a basis $B = \{b_1,...,b_n\}$. I want to show that every set $\{c_1,...,c_{n+1}\}$ has to be linearly dependent. I honestly don't even have an idea how to start. I mean it feels like this is going to be an indirect proof but I don't really know how to go from there. Any help or tips would be appreciated!

Comment: What properties does R satisfy? Is R commutative or unital? In general, the statement is not true. It is true if R is a commutative ring with unity.

Comment: @DonghanJang R is a commutative ring with unity, should have mentioned that

Comment: Oh, sorry. I misread your question. The statement is true for integral domains. This can be proved by considering the quotient field. I have no idea if there exists a zero divisor.